# Get Access Token and Refresh Token For Google Auth

Tags: google-app-engine, oauth

I have an app that I've registered with Google. I now have a client ID and a client secret. I am trying to figure out how to generate an access token and a refresh token for testing purposes.

How can I get an actual access token and a refresh token for testing purposes?

Comment: Go to the oauth2 playground

Comment: how does that let me create an access code for MY app? The only thing I see are Google's apps.

Comment: Aha. Not with playground. You need to implement the protocol.